# How important is it to till before sod installation?

Tags: sod

I got a few quotes for installing zoysia sod.  All of them are in the range of about $5000 bucks.  The difference is in the amount of pallets offered by each group:

1. Spotfill
2. About 75% of the yard.
3. 100% of the yard.

I am of course leaning towards the 3rd estimate.  The concern I have is the estimator told me they scalp the lawn.  He said they do not till because of the risk of damaging the sprinkler system.

Is that a big deal?  I feel like tilling is a lot of work and both of the other contractors do it.  So why do it if it isn't important right?  I'm no landscaping expert, so help me out.

Anything else I should look for before I choose?  They all have pretty good online reviews on https://www.homeadvisor.com/

Comment: How bad is your soil profile? It's not desert pavement with 3 inches of Oregon woodland sprinkled over the top or a similar horror, is it? There are some soils you do not want to till.

Comment: I don't know much about soil . I can tell you I live in a standard neighborhood in north Texas just north of Dallas.  We have clay soil and plenty of rocks.  The professionals haven't said anything about this kind of an issue (including the guy that doesn't till).

Comment: Find an out of the way place and dig a hole a couple feet down. If they brought in topsoil to cover the area around the house, you'll notice when you hit the original soil. Compare that depth to the tilling depth. Never been to Dallas so I don't know about soil there. Local university may have an agronomy or soil science website that can tell you what you're dealing with.